# Run processing algorithm from CSV

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to run the following algorithm which runs fine when I select a layer I imported from the CSV file in question but not when I just try to run if from the file itself.

```
input = '/media/path/points.csv=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=long&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:103172&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')
#input = layers[0]

output = '/media/path/outline.shp'

params = { 'DATE_FORMAT' : '', 'GROUP_FIELD' : 'rid', 'INPUT' : input, 'ORDER_FIELD' : 'vertex_ind', 'OUTPUT' : output }

res = processing.run('qgis:pointstopath', params)
```

I'm getting:

> File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py",
>   line 137, in runAlgorithm
>       raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm Could not load source layer for INPUT:
>   /media/path/points.csv=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=long&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:103172&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no
>   not found

Comment: Try replacing `layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')` with `layers = QgsVectorLayer("file:///" + input, "point", "delimitedtext")` and then replace `'INPUT' : input` with `'INPUT' : layers` in `params`.

Comment: This seems to get me closer, it looks to be reading the file but now I'm getting:

TypeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Joseph's insight this is what worked.

```
input_uri = 'file:////media/path/points.csv?delimiter=,&xField=long&yField=lat&crs=espg:103172&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'
output_uri = '/media/spath/out_paths.shp'
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(input_uri, 'New CSV','delimitedtext')

params = { 'DATE_FORMAT' : '', 'GROUP_FIELD' : 'rid', 'INPUT' : lyr, 'ORDER_FIELD' : 'vertex_ind', 'OUTPUT' : output_uri }
res = processing.run('qgis:pointstopath', params)
```