# How to specify GDAL driver to use for Processing INPUT?

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-processing, drivers

How can I specify a specific driver to be used by GDAL/OGR when running a tool via Processing? GDAL/OGR calls them prefixes to the connection string, e.g. https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gmlas.html#opening-syntax

E. g. this would use whatever driver GDAL/OGR decides to use for the GML file and works:

```
processing.run("gdal:convertformat", {
    'INPUT':'/tmp/tmpssu67zi9.gml','OUTPUT':'/tmp/test.shp'
})
```

But I need to make it use its GMLAS driver. Trying to add the prefix results in a crash because of the file not being found:

```
processing.run("gdal:convertformat", {
    'INPUT':'GMLAS:/tmp/tmpssu67zi9.gml','OUTPUT':'/tmp/test2.shp'
})
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 181, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: GMLAS:/tmp/tmpssu67zi9.gml not found
```

[Run processing algorithm from CSV](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331745/run-processing-algorithm-from-csv) might be related where a CSV connection string is also considered to be a file path but their solution of constructing a QgsVectorLayer "manually" and passing it to Processing is not an option for me. I want no extra setup for the `INPUT` parameter.